# Firebase Storage outage from Norway / Europe?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Our customers in Norway are currently getting 403 Forbidden on all Cloud Storage reads. This means our service is completely down for these customers. It's working fine for customers in Canada & America at least.

I can reproduce this in the Firebase Console directly, which means it isn't our code; our configuration hasn't changed that I'm aware of in the last 48 hours, and it was working from Norway yesterday. Steps:

1. VPN into Norway
2. Open Firebase Console in web browser, open Storage, upload a new JPG
3. Click on the uploaded image

Expected (and what happens from my native country, Canada): I can see image preview

Actual (when browsing from Norway): Error loading preview (Cloud storage 403 error).

I filed Case 10257786 with Google but it's several business days for a response...

Anyone else getting this problem too?

[image: firebase error]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question, but a support question for a vendor. (I realize that you've asked the vendor and they're slow to respond, but there isn't much the StackOverflow community can do about that).

Comment: @yshavit the Google Support page specifically instructs me to post queries like this here. So it's disappointing that you'll close it. What I want to learn is *is it me* or *is it everyone*, which is something the community here can help me with

Comment: Regardless, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not production support.  Google can't change the policies for posting here, as they don't run this side.  You should contact the vendor if you're having problems with an outage.  [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/) will definitely collect your feedback and respond.  There is also a [production status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/) for known issues.

Comment: @xaphod I agree that's disappointing — but the disappointment should be that Google doesn't support its own product, not that Stack Overflow doesn't provide free customer support for Google.

Comment: (That said, if I did use Firebase I would tell you if I were having issues with it, even though your question is off-topic for here. I don't, so I can't tell you.)

Comment: We're also seeing this problem, for customers in Sweden. We're implemeting fallback-logic loading the images via a proxy (positioned in another geographic region). We have also opened a support ticket with Firebase.

Let's hope for a quick resolution!

Comment: @MartinSuecia can you tell me your case # ? It would be hugely helpful because Google does not believe us that this isn't our fault

Comment: Sorry I don't have that, but I can ask my colleague tomorrow.
The issue seems to have been resolved in the last hour for us.

Comment: Yes thank you it is resolved now for us too!